# Changing Specific Values in SQL Database Table (warning: long post and MySQL/db ignorance)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have a database ('db') and I've screwed up.  For some of the items I submit to the db (items == 'events'), I need to change two values, value_one and value_two.  But the value to which I change value_one depends entirely on the value of value_two.  It's a disaster, I know.  Please allow me to explain and please forgive my ignorance of SQL (and the fact that outside of MySQL, I could only solve this using Python).

I have built a database to train a text classifier.  Each event within the database has a `category` (value_one) and a `sub_category` (value_two).  There are three categories (`nightlife`, `arts`, and `miscellany`) and four sub_categories (`live music`, `comedy`, `performance art`, and `visual art`).

```
If `sub_category` == `live music` **OR** `comedy`, **THEN** `category` == `nightlife.`
If `sub_category` == `performance art` **OR** `visual art`, **THEN** `category` == `arts.`
If there were multiple sub_categories, then `sub_category` == `Multiple Sub Cats:
['sub_cat1', 'sub_cat2', 'sub_cat3']` 
(often times `comedy` and `performance art,` for example) and `category` == `miscellany.`
```

Here's the problem: many `miscellany` submissions are wrongly classified, as the `sub_category` will read `Multiple Sub Cats: ['comedy']` or `Multiple Sub Cats: ['visual art'].`  Of course these should have been categorized as `nightlife` and `arts` and sub_categorized as `comedy` and `visual art` respectively.

I realize now that I simply should have created multiple tables and that my submission logic was flawed.  Still, I really need some advice, as I have over 24,000 (of 30,000) events which may have been mis-categorized.

My question is can I use MySQL syntax or Python to save it somehow??  I'm a bit over my skis here, so any suggestions (other than a reiteration that I suck) would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: please show a small sample of 20 records with bad data and the same 20 records after correction